# Having trouble instantiating using Strings

Tags: instantiation

I am trying to instantiate a student, gradstudent, and an MBAstudent in my main class and call the setter to set their first and last names, but im running into an error "The method setFirstName(String) in the type Student is not applicable for the arguments (Student)"

My Main class is as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student bob = new Student();
        GradStudent john = new GradStudent();
        MBAstudent michael = new MBAstudent();

        bob.setFirstName(bob);
        bob.setLastName(smith);
        bob.setmNumber(1);
        bob.setMatriculated(true);

        john.setFirstName(john);
        john.setLastName(white);
        john.setmNumber(2);
        john.setMatriculated(true);
        john.setAge(23);

        michael.setFirstName(michael);
        michael.setLastName(scott);
        michael.setmNumber(3);
        michael.setMatriculated(true);
        michael.setGpa(4.0);

    }
}
```

My Student Class:

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int mNumber;
    private boolean matriculated;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getmNumber() {
        return mNumber;
    }

    public void setmNumber(int mNumber) {
        this.mNumber = mNumber;
    }

    public boolean isMatriculated() {
        return matriculated;
    }

    public void setMatriculated(boolean matriculated) {
        this.matriculated = matriculated;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (firstName + " " + lastName + " has an MNumber of " + 
                mNumber + " and is enrolled");



    }
```

My GradStudent Class:

```
public class GradStudent extends Student {
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + " has an MNumber of " + 
                getmNumber() + " and is " + age + " years old and is enrolled");
    }
```

and my MBAstudent Class:

```
public class MBAstudent extends Student {
    private double gpa;

    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(double gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + " has an MNumber of " + 
                getmNumber() + " and has a GPA of " + gpa + " years old and is enrolled");
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Try this: `bob.setFirstName("bob");` instead of bob.setFirstName(bob); Your code `public void setFirstName(String firstName)` in Student class is looking for String as input. When you send `bob`, you're sending an object of type Student. When you send `"bob"`, you'd be sending a string - and that's what Student object's `setFirstName` wants. Change smith, john, etc. to strings with double-quotes and see how your program works.

Comment: wow. What a simple mistake! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are most welcome. You did an amazing job of describing your problem along with code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be having this problem due to not putting your String parameters inside double-quotes(e.g., michael.setFirstName("michael");
        michael.setLastName("scott");). Put all arguments of functions setFirstName() and setLastName() inside double-quotes and your problem will be solved. Have a nice day! You can also print each instance's members with get functions to be sure